# How to list all reachable ports?

Tags: networking

I can test some specific port by `nc -zv <server_ip> <port>` or by accessing it in browser `http://<server_ip>:<port>/`.

But how to get a list of all reachable ports on server?

Update:
Also I was able to scan port range with this command:

`nc -zv <server_ip> <port_range_start>-<port_range_end> 2>&1 | grep succeeded`

Comment: That's a big topic , you should start from [here](https://nmap.org/book/man-port-scanning-techniques.html)

Comment: Short answer if the server is reacheable over a public network you could use  `nmap -p "*" <server_ip>` or `nmap -p <port_range_start>-<port_range_end> <server_ip>`

Answer (score 2):

```
nmap -p1-65535 ${SERVER_IP}
nmap -sU -p1-65535 ${SERVER_IP}
```

The first variant scans all TCP ports; the second all UDP ports.  Note that if you try broad portscanning over a public network, or against a server/network for which you are not an administrator, you are likely to trigger an IDS and get blocked.

Answer (score 2):

Net map is a powerful network scanner.  If you wish to know more about the target computer and it's open ports use:

```
sudo nmap -O target.host.com
```

or, for example

```
sudo nmap -O 192.168.1.1
```

This will report open ports, and information about the target machine.
There are many many options for nmap. Refer to the info or man pages

Comment: The `-O` option does not scan all ports; only the 1000 most commonly bound TCP ports.